# Ubuntu 16.04 and Nvidia graphic card (nvs 310) randomly freezes when opening programs

Tags: drivers, nvidia, gnome, opengl, gpu

I'm running ubuntu 16.04 LTS, gnome-shell with [adapta gtk theme](https://github.com/adapta-project/adapta-gtk-theme) and several gnome extensions (with tweak tool).

I'm having issues when starting up programs (may be related to resize of windows?). Ubuntu randomly freezes when I start chrome, slack, spotify or atom (programs I use alot). I'm sometime able to move the mouse abit after it freezes and may be able to get into CLI using ctrl+alt+f keys, but I'm unable to get X working again without a restart of the computer.

I'm suspecting this is related to X settings/graphic cards drivers.
My graphic card is a Nvidia (NVS 310) running inside a HP Z420 desktop computer.
I'm using nvidia proprietary drivers (currently 384.111):
[Additional drivers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9lDVW.png)

Some screenshots from gnome-tweak-tool so you can see what theme and extensions I run:
[Apperance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XqRqw.png)
[Extensions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Qmgx.png)

Here are some debug information from syslog the last time ubuntu froze:

`Apr  3 14:57:24 dbus[1151]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.bluez' unit='dbus-org.bluez.service'
Apr  3 14:57:26 kernel: [10590.565125] NVRM: GPU at PCI:0000:05:00: GPU-cfb2498e-11d0-8fbb-a8a5-b843a1ea6bbb
Apr  3 14:57:26 kernel: [10590.565129] NVRM: Xid (PCI:0000:05:00): 13, Graphics Exception on GPC 0: 3D-Z SYSMEM KIND Violation. Coordinates: (0x0, 0x0)
Apr  3 14:57:26 kernel: [10590.565135] NVRM: Xid (PCI:0000:05:00): 13, Graphics Exception: ESR 0x500420=0x80004000 0x500434=0x0 0x500438=0x20000 0x50043c=0x310000
Apr  3 14:57:26 kernel: [10590.565164] NVRM: Xid (PCI:0000:05:00): 13, Graphics Exception: ChID 0003, Class 00009297, Offset 00001b0c, Data 1000f010
Apr  3 14:57:26 kernel: [10590.635461] NVRM: Xid (PCI:0000:05:00): 31, Ch 0000000f, engmask 00000101, intr 10000000
Apr  3 14:57:26 kernel: [10590.660408] code[22010]: segfault at 4 ip 00007ff80e8fb027 sp 00007ffe2972a058 error 6 in libnvidia-glcore.so.384.111[7ff80d648000+149e000]
Apr  3 14:57:28 kernel: [10592.016774] NVRM: Xid (PCI:0000:05:00): 13, Graphics Exception on GPC 0: 3D-Z KIND Violation. Coordinates: (0xdc0, 0x258)
Apr  3 14:57:28 kernel: [10592.016781] NVRM: Xid (PCI:0000:05:00): 13, Graphics Exception: ESR 0x500420=0x80000080 0x500434=0x2580dc0 0x500438=0x20000 0x50043c=0x100fe
Apr  3 14:57:28 kernel: [10592.016808] NVRM: Xid (PCI:0000:05:00): 13, Graphics Exception: ChID 0003, Class 00009297, Offset 00001b0c, Data 1000f010
Apr  3 14:58:31 kernel: [10655.446415] NVRM: Xid (PCI:0000:05:00): 31, Ch 00000004, engmask 00000101, intr 10000000`

Debug from a freeze that I was able to recover from after waiting some time and changing tty (this time I was starting slack):

`Apr  4 20:18:12 dbus[1111]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.bluez' unit='dbus-org.bluez.service'
Apr  4 20:18:13 slack.desktop[28951]: Creating Slack Application
Apr  4 20:18:13 org.gnome.zeitgeist.Engine[19129]: ** (zeitgeist-datahub:19627): WARNING **: downloads-directory-provider.vala:120: Couldn't process /home/user/Downloads/__dummy__: Error when getting information for file '/home/user/Downloads/__dummy__': No such file or directory
Apr  4 20:18:22 kernel: [102248.177810] NVRM: GPU at PCI:0000:05:00: GPU-cfb2498e-11d0-8fbb-a8a5-b843a1ea6bbb
Apr  4 20:18:22 kernel: [102248.177816] NVRM: Xid (PCI:0000:05:00): 31, Ch 00000003, engmask 00000101, intr 10000000
Apr  4 20:18:22 kernel: [102248.207066] NVRM: Xid (PCI:0000:05:00): 13, Graphics Exception on GPC 0: 3D-C SYSMEM KIND Violation. Coordinates: (0x0, 0x0)
Apr  4 20:18:22 kernel: [102248.207072] NVRM: Xid (PCI:0000:05:00): 13, Graphics Exception: ESR 0x500420=0x80008000 0x500434=0x0 0x500438=0x2a00 0x50043c=0x310011
Apr  4 20:18:22 kernel: [102248.207102] NVRM: Xid (PCI:0000:05:00): 13, Graphics Exception: ChID 0009, Class 00009297, Offset 00001978, Data 00000000
Apr  4 20:18:22 kernel: [102248.243530] slack[28993]: segfault at 4 ip 00007f9e63051027 sp 00007ffee9276a78 error 6 in libnvidia-glcore.so.384.111[7f9e61d9e000+149e000]
Apr  4 20:18:23 kernel: [102249.256946] NVRM: Xid (PCI:0000:05:00): 13, Graphics Exception on GPC 0: 3D-Z SYSMEM KIND Violation. Coordinates: (0x0, 0x0)
Apr  4 20:18:23 kernel: [102249.256952] NVRM: Xid (PCI:0000:05:00): 13, Graphics Exception: ESR 0x500420=0x80004000 0x500434=0x0 0x500438=0x20000 0x50043c=0x3100fe
Apr  4 20:18:23 kernel: [102249.256977] NVRM: Xid (PCI:0000:05:00): 13, Graphics Exception: ChID 0003, Class 00009297, Offset 00001b0c, Data 1000f010
Apr  4 20:18:59 gnome-session[19267]: [19869:19869:0404/201859.783295:ERROR:gles2_cmd_decoder.cc(5385)] GLES2DecoderImpl::ResizeOffscreenFramebuffer failed because offscreen FBO was incomplete.
Apr  4 20:18:59 gnome-session[19267]: [19869:19869:0404/201859.784908:ERROR:gles2_cmd_decoder.cc(3708)] ContextResult::kFatalFailure: Could not allocate offscreen buffer storage.
Apr  4 20:18:59 gnome-session[19267]: Window manager warning: last_user_time (102259129) is greater than comparison timestamp (102251425).  This most likely represents a buggy client sending inaccurate timestamps in messages such as _NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW.  Trying to work around...
Apr  4 20:18:59 gnome-session[19267]: Window manager warning: 0x1c00005 (Slack - TR) appears to be one of the offending windows with a timestamp of 102259129.  Working around...
Apr  4 20:19:00 kernel: [102285.817780] slack[29203]: segfault at 4 ip 00007f4ff2794027 sp 00007ffd63f15b88 error 6 in libnvidia-glcore.so.384.111[7f4ff14e1000+149e000]
Apr  4 20:19:02 acpid: client 18872[0:0] has disconnected
Apr  4 20:19:02 kernel: [102288.506058] slack[29218]: segfault at 4 ip 00007f005234c027 sp 00007ffd2f99a0b8 error 6 in libnvidia-glcore.so.384.111[7f0051099000+149e000]
Apr  4 20:19:02 acpid: client connected from 18872[0:0]
Apr  4 20:19:02 acpid: 1 client rule loaded
Apr  4 20:19:20 acpid: client 18872[0:0] has disconnected
Apr  4 20:19:21 systemd[1]: Started Getty on tty3.
Apr  4 20:19:24 acpid: client connected from 18872[0:0]
Apr  4 20:19:24 acpid: 1 client rule loaded`

This have been going on for a while and it's pretty annoying since I sometime have to restart my computer several times a day because it's getting unresponsive. It's very random, it can suddenly work for days without it freezing.

From the information given over and the syslog, any suggestion on what I can do to try and fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: FYI: I've re-installed ubuntu from scratch several times to see if it helps, but no luck. If I use other drivers than nvidia proprietary I'm unable to use high resolutions

Comment: Trying to run a network stream in vlc does not work at all.
Output from vlc:
`[00007f9e7800f5c8] avcodec decoder: Using NVIDIA VDPAU Driver Shared Library  384.111  Tue Dec 19 22:55:29 PST 2017 for hardware decoding.
[1]    15558 segmentation fault (core dumped)  vlc
```
Output from syslog:
```
Apr  4 20:58:59  [  786.450333] vlc[18401]: segfault at 1b0 ip 00007f9e74e67122 sp 00007f9e7f9b4770 error 6 in libvdpau_nvidia.so.384.111[7f9e74e41000+7d000]
`

Comment: Apr 25 08:21:53 kernel: [ 965.272816] code[8946]: segfault at 4 ip 00007f81ffc23027 sp 00007ffc5291b658 error 6 in libnvidia-glcore.so.384.111[7f81fe970000+149e000]
Apr 25 08:21:53 kernel: [ 965.286126] NVRM: GPU at PCI:0000:05:00: GPU-cfb2498e-11d0-8fbb-a8a5-b843a1ea6bbb
Apr 25 08:21:53 kernel: [ 965.286130] NVRM: Xid (PCI:0000:05:00): 31, Ch 00000003, engmask 00000101, intr 10000000
Apr 25 08:21:53 kernel: [ 965.369134] NVRM: Xid (PCI:0000:05:00): 31, Ch 00000003, engmask 00000101, intr 10000000